# Amplitude detection

Tags: detector, amplitude

Why is second analog multiplier(marked with red color) used to detect the amplitude of the input signal in this circuit instead of diode?
The point of this circuit is to maintain the output level of the first multiplier constant all the time.

[image]

Comment: Looks more like a true detector with no offset and some gain

Comment: It makes sense. But why is it used here?

Comment: I dont know why is it beign used here. I dont understand its concpet of squaring the voltage, it seems like it is giving him some DC offset when I square it and that is it.

Comment: It seems to be AGC output, but why is squaring used to detect amplitude?

Comment: true RMS detector?  is this a test to guess where you got this?

Comment: Do some more reading https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/design-handbooks/ADI_Multiplier_Applications_Guide.pdf?doc=AD633.pdf

Comment: I read the book you sent me, I am sorry but I still dont understand the point of second multiplier in order to detect the amplitude. In the book you sent me squaring input voltage is usally part of something bigger, but in my circuit its only prupose is to detect the amplitude and I seem to fail to understand why is it beign used.

Comment: Where did you get this RMs detector cct?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not remember that, that is the reason why I am posting it here. If I knew where I got it I think it would have come with an explanation.

Comment: Thats pretty vague then if you have no idea what its for. i suggest as V^2 is proportional to power it measures power into a fixed load.

Comment: As I said previously it seems to be AGC but I am confused why use multiplier instead of some diode type peak detector.

Comment: I’ve never seen this before yet it shud be obvious with the equation it is solving when you equate the op amp inputs, no?

Comment: I guess that is just how circuit works. Equations fit and that is all is needed.

Answer (score 4):

When you square a sine wave, you get a DC term and a term at twice the frequency.  The RC filter is used to eliminate the double frequency term. The DC term is proportional to the square of the input level and is fed back to the input to keep the signal level constant at the output of the first multiplier. The multiplier eliminates the need for a precision rectifier and has no offset voltage to worry about.

Comment: So DC terms contains information about the peak then that peak is compared to reference?